# Do I still need a backend like RoR or Django if I use Firebase?

Tags: firebase

I am a Front-end developer with limited backend knowledge.

My question is do I need other backend frameworks like Django or Ruby on Rails if I use Firebase as a backend? In other words, can I solely depend on Firebase as a backend and build a single page web application or Mobile application without writing a single line of backend code?

Thanks for your time viewing the question.

Comment: I do think that firebase is enough as long as you use it to store and retrieve every data you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also looking for a platform to minimize server code and I found that firebase can help a lot. 
You will get plenty of docs on net.  You can start at angular fire  + firebase doc
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html

Following document was helpful for me to design my app, which requires some amount of off-line processing too.
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/03/where-does-firebase-fit-in-your-app.html